# ( was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've read most of the topics about this already, and understand that complex if/then blocks are a pain in the Windows command line, so I tried scaling back, and I still end up with the "( was unexpected at this time" error.

I feel like it has to do with where %confirm% is being set, but I'm really unsure. Originally I had a goto in the block, which I read is a no-go, so I tried working around that with a nested if/if/else. No dice.

I'm can't think of anything more basic than what I'm doing, as the inner workings of the command shell are beyond my ken.

First version:

```
@echo off

TITLE cleanup

:: make user confirm they want to cleanup old epub conversion files
set /p confirm = "Are you sure? (y/n): "

if %confirm% == y (
    rm ePub
    rm IP
    rm OP
    md IP
    exit
) else (
    if %confirm% == n (
        exit
    ) else (
        set /p confirm = "Are you sure? (y/n): "
    )
)
```

Current, scaled-back version:

```
 @echo off

TITLE cleanup

:: make user confirm they want to cleanup old epub conversion files
set /p confirm = "Are you sure? (y/n): "

if %confirm% == y (
    rm ePub
    rm IP
    rm OP
    md IP
    exit
) else ( 
    exit
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code has broken syntax when a variable is actually empty.  Try

```
if "%confirm%" == "y" (
```

which guarantees there's always something on the left side of the `==`.

Answer (score 1):

1- In Batch files, both `SET var=value` and `SET /P var=prompt` commands takes as the variable name the complete string that is placed before the equal sign, *including spaces*! This means that in this command:

```
set /p confirm = "Are you sure? (y/n): "
```

... the variable name is: "confirm+space". You may check this point placing this line after the set /p:

```
echo Value of "confirm": %confirm%  Value of "confirm ": %confirm %
```

In conclusion: **Never leave spaces before equal sign in SET command**.

2- In the same way, the value assigned to the variable or used as prompt is the complete string placed after the equal sign, *including quotes*. If you want to delimit the value/prompt used: **Enclose in quotes both the variable name and the value/prompt**; for example:

```
set /p "confirm=Are you sure? (y/n): "
```

This is particularly true in SET /A command when the expression may contain special Batch characters: `SET /A "var=1<<16"`. By the while, in the particular case of SET /A command the spaces between variable name and equal sign *are ignored*: `SET /A var = 1` `echo %var%`, not `%var %`.

3- Independently of two previous points, if a variable value may be empty (like a variable read by SET /P) the value should be enclosed in quotes in the IF command (and also the value vs. it is compared) as Ben Voigt previously mentioned. This happen because SET /P command *does NOT modify* the variable if the user just press Enter, so you always should initialize the variable before SET /P command with a *default value*; otherwise, the program may process a value entered in previous execution or previous cycle!

```
set confirm=n
set /p "confirm=Are you sure? (y/n): "
if /I "%confirm%" == "y" (
```

Previous IF still requires the quotes because the user may enter just spaces! Also, it use /I switch to ignore case, because the user may enter Y or N in uppper-case.

I hope it helps...

Antonio